# Concurrent AJAX requests not working. Newest request overwrites previous request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, web

My webpage features a table where each row has a "+" button so that a mini table appears. The mini table houses data from a super slow database so I am having the data come in through ajax requests. My problem is rooted in a certain situation. Suppose you pressed a plus button causing an AJAX request and while waiting you press another plus button. The second ajax request causes the first request to never come back. In other words the newest request overwrites all previous pending requests. Any idea why this might be happening? I feel like this might just be what happens when you don't use jQuery to handle AJAX but I am not sure and I couldn't find anything that said that was the case. I am appending my code below. Any help is appreciated!

```
function fetchSINamesForVariantAJAX(latestBuild, variantToExpand){
if (latestBuild ==  "") {
    //document.getElementById(subTableId).innerHTML = ""; 
    return;
} 
else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            spinner.stop();
            var variantRow = variantToExpand + "Row";
            if (document.getElementById(variantRow).rows.length == 1){
                var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                var SINames = json['SIs'];
                var locations = json['locations'];
                var SIBuilds = json['SIBuilds'];
                for (var i = 0; i < SINames.length ; i++){
                    var row = document.getElementById(variantRow).insertRow(-1);
                    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                    var SILinkURL = "exampleWebsite.com/name.php?names=" + SINames[i];
                    cell.innerHTML = "<a href=\"" + SILinkURL + "\">" + SINames[i] + "</a>";

                    cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                    var fullLocation = locations[i] + "\\" + SIBuilds[i];
                    cell.innerHTML = "<a href=\"" + fullLocation + "\">" + fullLocation + "</a>";

                    cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                    cell.innerHTML = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //create the GET message to be sent using AJAX window
    var stateToSend = "SITableGeneratorFromVariant.php?";
    stateToSend += "latestBuild=" + latestBuild;    
    xmlhttp.open("GET", stateToSend, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you be more specific on the behavior you're seeing?  An AJAX request wouldn't "cancel" another request.  In the browser's debugging tools, what happens with the two requests?  What are their responses from the server?  When you debug this code, what happens when each one returns and invoked `onreadystatechange`?

Comment: I think it is because your var xmlhttp request is not scoped in the function, so everytime you call that function xmlhttp request is a global var and you are overwriting it. Try declaring var xmlhttp at the top of your function

Comment: I took your advice and looked into the debugging. I noticed that I never declared xmlhttp as a var so I added the line "var xmlhttp;" at the very top of the function and that fixed the problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that you overwrite your xmlhttp variable with a new one each time a new AJAX call gets done try declaring it inside the function:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
```